# docker-compose state always restarting

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongo-express

When I created the docker container, the state is up initially and shows port 8081:8081. But when I hit http://localhost:8081, the browser refuses to connect. After that, If I list the container then automatically the state is restarting and there is no port id.

Terminal: [1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctTii.png

my docker-compose.yml file: [2]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJewi.png

Comment: check the logs of the restarting container

Comment: Have you looked at the container logs? Is there any information there about why the container seems to be crashing?

Comment: Please don't post images. Copy/paste the text and use the formatting tools.